# small python3 script to plot quickly data on command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, sys

I was looking for a fast way to show from terminal command line the plot 2D between 2 columns of data from an input file.

I found this link : [simple-plotting](https://leancrew.com/all-this/2013/12/simple-plotting-from-the-command-line/)

especially the `plot` script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

fcns = sys.argv[1].split(';')
minx = eval(sys.argv[2])
maxx = eval(sys.argv[3])
plt.xlim(minx, maxx)
try:
  miny = float(sys.argv[4])
  maxy = float(sys.argv[5])
  plt.ylim(miny, maxy)
except IndexError:
  pass

x = linspace(minx, maxx, 100)
for i, f in enumerate(fcns):
  y = eval(f)
  plt.plot(x, y, "-", linewidth=2)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='both', color='#aaaaaa')
plt.savefig(sys.stdout, format='png')
```

1. First, Normal using is (I am on MacOS Big Sur) :

   `$ plot 'tan(x); x' pi 3*pi/2-.01 0 5`

but I get the folowing error (`pi` doesn't seem to be recognized)

```
zsh: no matches found: 3*pi/2-.01
```

2. Secondly, once this first minor issue will be solved, I would like to modify it in order to not be obliged to specify `minx` and `maxx`.

For this, I have to find the minimum and maximum of x-axis dat and I would to do the same for y-axis values.

To carry out it, I would try :

```
# Chose the first column x-axis : sys.argv[2]
# Chose the first column y-axis : sys.argv[3]
columnx = sys.argv[2]
columny = sys.argv[3]

data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])

minx = np.min(data[:,columnx])
maxx = np.max(data[:,columnx])
miny = np.min(data[:,columny])
maxy = np.max(data[:,columny])

# Limits
plt.xlim(minx, maxx)
plt.ylim(miny, maxy)

# Plot
x = linspace(minx, maxx, 100)
for i, f in enumerate(fcns):
  y = eval(f)
  plt.plot(x, y, "-", linewidth=2)
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='both', color='#aaaaaa')
plt.savefig(sys.stdout, format='png')
```

But I realized that with this code snippet, I can't have the both functionalities : plot a function like with `$ plot 'tan(x); x' pi 3*pi/2-.01 0 5` command and in the same time being able to do :

```
$ plot input.dat 1 2
```

to plot with line for column 1 vs column 2.

If someone had a suggestion to firstly debug the question 1) and 2) to get both functionalities : plot a function and plot data file 2 columns, this would be fine to tell it.

Sorry about `eval`, I know it is not recommended but other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: It won't recognize "pi" because it isn't defined globally, but it is defined in numpy.  Likewise "tan".  So change your command-line arguments to `plot 'np.tan(x); x' np.pi 3*np.pi/2-.01 0 5`.

Comment: Also, now I read it again, zsh will try to expand '*' so escape it.  Thus: `plot 'np.tan(x); x' np.pi 3\*np.pi/2-.01 0 5`

Comment: @bgstech . Thanks for your quick answer. Finally, I remain on a fork of my second issue, i.e being able to launch the Python script from command line under the form : `$ plot input1.data 0 1 &` and replot another curve with another `input2.dat` on the same window plot by launching a second command : `$ plot input2.data 0 1 &` while having the 2 curves on the same interactive window. But this will be another post. Regards

Comment: in case, the link of this fork is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402002/python-plot-script-launched-2-times-while-drawing-the-2-curves-on-the-same-inter